# Rejecting mapping update error in firebase when pushing data to elastic search index

Tags: node.js, firebase, postman

I am trying to use Firebase cloud functions to push data to my ElasticSearch index and am experiencing some error in the Firebase. Where could the problem be?

Here is my index.js function code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const request = require('request-promise')

exports.indexPostsToElastic = functions.database.ref('/posts/{post_id}')
        .onWrite((change,context) =>{
        let postData = change.after.val();
        let post_id = context.params.post_id;

        console.log('Indexing post',postData);

        let elasticSearchConfig = functions.config().elasticsearch;


        let elasticSearchUrl = elasticSearchConfig.url + 'posts/' + post_id;
        let elasticSearchMethod = postData ? 'POST' : 'DELETE';

        let elasticSearchRequest = {
            method:elasticSearchMethod,
                url: elasticSearchUrl,
                auth:{
                    username : elasticSearchConfig.username,
                    password : elasticSearchConfig.password,
                },
                body: postData,
                json : true
              };
              return request(elasticSearchRequest).then(response => {
                  return console.log("ElasticSearch response", response);
              })
            });
```

And below is the error am receiving in Firebase

```
StatusCodeError: 400 - {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Rejecting mapping update to [posts] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, -LcVpBay0SLV3c6fnpgt]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Rejecting mapping update to [posts] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, -LcVpBay0SLV3c6fnpgt]"},"status":400}
    at new StatusCodeError (/user_code/node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request-promise-core/lib/errors.js:32:15)
```

Here is my index code in postman

```
{
    "mappings":{
        "properties":{
                "city":{
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "contact_email":{
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "country":{
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "description":{
                "type": "text"
                },
                "image":{
                "type": "text"
                },
                "post_id":{
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "state_province":{
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "title":{
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message suggests, multiple mapping types have been removed.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/removal-of-types.html

Comment: Thankyou but could you please guide me on how to update index mappings in postman. The documentation in the link doesn't really guide on steps one should follow to update a mapping in postman